# How to adjust Flutter TextField height?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I'm building a social networking app with Flutter and all the TextFields are very tall. I have tried adjusting the `contentPadding` parameter but it doesn't work. The problem goes away when I remove the `inputDecoration` (i.e. set it to `null`) but in that case I am unable to display any hint text.

I've also tried wrapping the TextField inside a Container and setting the height of the Container but that doesn't help either. It just distorts the entire TextField.

[image: screenshot of app with extended TextField]

Answer (score 27):

[image]

Use these two lines to control `TextFormField` Height inside `InputDecoration` .

```
isDense: true, 
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
```

Full example

```
Material(
                elevation: 4,
                shadowColor: Colors.blue,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: searchProvider.searchController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'hintText',
                        isDense: true, // important line
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),// control your hints text size
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 2, color: Colors.black54, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        fillColor:  Colors.white30 ,
                        filled: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30), borderSide: BorderSide.none)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: This! I put the `TextFormField` in a `Container` and changed the `contentPadding`. Worked like a charm.  Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Try this ! This will decrease slightly !

```
               TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,0,10,0),
                        //The above line will help !
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Name',
                        labelStyle:
                            TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17),
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17),
                    ),
```

Comment: it seems like this is an issue with the Flutter installation because in my other apps the TextFields are still the normal size. I was looking for a more robust solution but I'll give this a shot

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```dart
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        isDense: true,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: Strings.settingGoodsTitle
    )
)
```